# Unable to read a text file from external storage (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oneplus7

I wrote a small script to check whether a text file exists in a folder. I have created a folder named depth_estimation and it contains a file named K.txt (Attaching screenshot for reference). While I try to read the text file it throws an error stating the file is not found but when I checked the folder the file actually exists. I am just a beginner![image] [image]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Post your code as text. No images.

Comment: `depth_estimation` ? depth_detection?

Comment: Thank you blackapps!! Was struggling for a long time. Saved a day.